# Android: List Fragment Data not showing with Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to display a listview of Persons in a list fragment by using a Custom ArrayAdapter. I used a class called PersonData to initialize a list and fill it with dummy info. My application runs just fine but nothing is being shown in the List. I'm very new to Android programming and would appreciate if anyone can spot why. Below are my XML and Java Files

**Person.Java**

```
package com.example.mksmasr.simplefragments;
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private int age;
    Person(){}
    Person(String n,int a){
        this.name = n;
        this.age = a;

    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {

        return status;
    }


    public void setName(String n)
    {
        this.name = n;

    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;

    }

    public void setAge(int a){
        this.age = a;
    }

  public  int getAge(){return age;}
}
```

**PersonData.Java**

```
package com.example.mksmasr.simplefragments;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mksmasr on 11/23/16.
 */

public class PersonData {
    public List<Person> people;
    public List<Person> getPeople(){return this.people;}


    public PersonData()
    {
        people.add(new Person("John Smith",21));
        people.add(new Person("Brad Pitt",21));
        people.add(new Person("Jimmy Hendricks",50));
        people.add(new Person("Steven James",21));
        people.add(new Person("Elizabeth Johnson",21));





    }
}
```

**PersonArrayAdapter.Java**

```
package com.example.mksmasr.simplefragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;



public class PersonArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Person> objects;


    public PersonArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Person> objects) {
        super(context, resource,objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Person p = objects.get(pos);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_listitem,null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
        tv.setText(p.getName());

        return view;



    }
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
    package com.example.mksmasr.simplefragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //  RelationshipFragment frag = new RelationshipFragment();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




}
```

**RelationshipFragment.Java**

```
package com.example.mksmasr.simplefragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.List;



public class RelationshipFragment extends ListFragment {

    List<Person> relationships  = new PersonData().getPeople();

    public RelationshipFragment(){}



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PersonArrayAdapter adapter = new PersonArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.person_listitem,this.relationships);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_listitem,container,false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mksmasr.simplefragments.MainActivity">




    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/relationship_fragment"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="No data"/>






    </LinearLayout>
```

**person_listitem.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- The background enables the activation appearance on tablets -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />





</LinearLayout>
```

**relationship_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mksmasr.simplefragments.MainActivity">







    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="No data"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your `Fragment` is not being used anywhere, and the `Activity`'s `List` is empty.

Comment: @MikeM. im sorry can you be more specific, where do i need to instantiate the fragment?

Comment: Nowhere are you including `RelationshipFragment` in your `Activity`'s layout, nor are you loading an instance of it dynamically, so it and its `ListView` are never shown. You do have a `ListView` in your `Activity`, which you probably don't really want, but its `List` is empty, so nothing's showing there, either. The [developer page for Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) demonstrates the two basic ways to add a `Fragment` to your `Activity`.

Comment: Ah i see, so would i need to somehow convert my "relationships" List of Persons in RelationshipFragment into a string List? thats kind of the part i dont get, i tried instantiating RelationshipFragment and returning the list and then using that list in the MainActivity and it gave me an Error

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're saying. If you want your `Fragment` to hold the `ListView`, get rid of the `ListView` in the `Activity`, and somehow add the `Fragment` to the `Activity`. Look at this section of that page: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you, I realized i never initialized an instance of my fragment class in the MainActivity and therefore my list was never actually being created. You helped a lot!